# Consumer to RabbitMQ stream - Bad header / Command not implemented 0 buff:0

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-stream

I have this configuration in docker-compose:

```
services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_PLUGINS=rabbitmq_stream   // stream plugin enabled?
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rabbitmq
```

My consumer to the stream looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-go-client/pkg/amqp"
    "github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-go-client/pkg/stream"
)

func main() {
    // Create an environment
    env, err := stream.NewEnvironment(
        stream.NewEnvironmentOptions().
            SetHost("localhost").
            SetPort(5672).           // 5552
            SetUser("rabbitmq").     // Replace with your username
            SetPassword("rabbitmq"), // Replace with your password
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create environment: %s", err)
    }

    // Define a handler for incoming messages
    handleMessage := func(consumerContext stream.ConsumerContext, message *amqp.Message) {
        for _, z := range message.Data {
            fmt.Println("Received message:", string(z))
        }
    }

    // Create a consumer
    _, err = env.NewConsumer(
        "your_stream_name",
        handleMessage,
        stream.NewConsumerOptions().SetConsumerName("my_consumer"),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create consumer: %s", err)
    }

    select {}
}
```

but I get this error:

> ```
> 2023/12/14 11:03:16 [warn] - Command not implemented 0 buff:0 
> 2023/12/14 11:03:26 [error] - timeout 10000 ns - waiting Code, operation: commandPeerProperties
> 2023/12/14 11:03:26 [error] - Can't set the peer-properties. Check if the stream server is running/reachable
> 2023/12/14 11:03:26 Failed to create environment: timeout 10000 ms - waiting Code, operation: commandPeerProperties
> ```

in the RabbitMQ server logs, I see this:

> wss-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-12-14 16:01:07.964018+00:00 [info] <0.9.0> Time
> to start RabbitMQ: 30736437 us wss-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-12-14
> 16:02:28.713781+00:00 [info] <0.752.0> accepting AMQP connection
> <0.752.0> (192.168.65.1:33513 -> 192.168.240.3:5672) wss-rabbitmq-1  |
> 2023-12-14 16:02:28.714007+00:00 [error] <0.752.0> closing AMQP
> connection <0.752.

> wss-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-12-14 16:02:28.714007+00:00 [error] <0.752.0>
> {bad_header,<<0,0,0,243,0,17,0,1>>} wss-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-12-14
> 16:03:16.808111+00:00 [info] <0.781.0> accepting AMQP connection
> <0.781.0> (192.168.65.1:33844 -> 192.168.240.3:5672)

> wss-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-12-14 16:03:16.808803+00:00 [error] <0.781.0> closing AMQP
> connection <0.781.0> (192.168.65.1:33844 -> 192.168.240.3:5672):
> wss-rabbitmq-1  | 2023-12-14 16:03:16.808803+00:00 [error] <0.781.0>
> {bad_header,<<0,0,0,243,0,17,0,1>>}0> (192.168.65.1:33513 -> 192.168.240.3:5672):
> Blockquote

I ensured that the streams plugin was enabled using:

```
docker exec 1d0e959696d8 rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream
```

and even though the RMQ logs said the plugin was successfully enabled, I still got the same error..

Comment: It's all running locally and username/pass are correct, looks like it's some RMQ config missing, but the streams plugin should be enabled with the env variable - RABBITMQ_PLUGINS=rabbitmq_stream

Answer (score 1):

The client you are using needs the stream plugin enabled.

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream rabbitmq_stream_management
```

Read the documentation about: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-go-client?tab=readme-ov-file#run-server-with-docker

Then you need to expose the correct port `5552` ( stream port)
`5672` is for AMQP

please see this link:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/stream-core-plugin-comparison.html

Comment: thanks, will try it, will this ENV var work? `RABBITMQ_PLUGINS=rabbitmq_stream,rabbitmq_stream_management`?

Sadly this env var doesn't seem to work

Comment: I also see this in the logs - vibe-rabbitmq  | 2023-12-14 22:59:00.258182+00:00 [warning] <0.618.0> HTTP listener registry could not find context rabbitmq_management_tls